# Check if List has List as element

Tags: python, python-3.x

assume I have following:

```
z = [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]
```

Now I want to check if it contains a list or not.
I've tried something like:

```
if not isinstance(z[0], list):
    z = [z]
    print("Im no list")
```

---

If its the case that

```
z = [[3.0, 1.0, 0.2]]
```

then the `if not isinstance(z[0], list):` should not trigger, but it does.

Can somebody give me a hint how I can check, if the list contains another list?

Edit: I'm sorry for the initially confusing question. I had the right answer already and it's also posted beneath. I was not attentive and my problem was caused by the fact, that I first had a list and later on a numpy array.

Comment: what is `z` ??? Is it `score` ?

Comment: [After your 3rd edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/34955189/3), it doesn't trigger the `print` for me.

Comment: maybe you expect that `z` is `[ [ ... ] ] ` but `z` is normal `[ ...]` - maybe `print(z)` to check it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
isinstance(scores[0], list)
```

will return `False`. Using `if not` will mean that the clause in the `if` will become true hence the body will be executed.

When `z` contains a `list` as in `z = [[1, 2, 3]]` it doesn't trigger since the `isinstance` call returns `True` and `if not` reverts that to `False`.

In order to efficiently check if a list contains another list consider using `any`, if it returns `True` you know it does:

```
>>> z = [1, 2, [3.0, 1.0, 0.2]]
>>> any(isinstance(i, list) for i in z)
True
```

Comment: Sorry, I did another mistake. I mean it should not trigger if z = [[ ... ]]

Comment: It doesn't trigger when `z=[[...]]`

Comment: Yes, i just realized that its not because of that, its because later in the context im using a numpy array.. i marked for close - sorry, apparently im a bit to tired

Answer (score 0):

Give a list "lst", this will print out all the elements that are lists.

```
for i in lst:
    if isinstance(i, list):
      print(i, lst[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in z:
    if type(i)==list:
        print("its a list")
```